# SSM Connection timout after 15 mins when attempting to connect to redshift through bastion host

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, amazon-redshift, aws-ssm, bastion-host

I have an issue where I am connecting to redshift using a jumpbox/bastion host via a ssm document. I can run one query and then the connection appears to timeout after 15 mins. I would like to sustain the connection for an hour or more. I am kinda at a loss why this timeout is happening and was wondering if anybody has some pointers or has encountered the issue before and knows what the problem might be?

Comment: Maybe you have to take a look at the WLM Queue to check which queue your connection is tied to and see if there is a timeout setting setup that needs to be increased.